# `matplotlib`: `self._chachedRenderer` fails `assert self._cachedRenderer is not None`, when calling `draw_artist` on a patch?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Based on *the* John Hunter's [answer to a question regarding using patches in animations here](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/blit-animation-with-patches-td25634.html), I am under the impression that:

1. I can create a `patch` object, with [its animated stated being `True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135489/matplotlib-what-is-the-purpose-of-an-artists-animated-state).
2. Add it to an existing `axis` (let's say the `axis` object is called `ax`) using the `add_patch` method.
3. Then when I want to draw the `patch`, I do: `ax.draw_artist(patch)`.

Doing this, I am faced with the following error:

```
  File "environment.py", line 254, in animation_function
    ax.draw_artist(patches[index])
  File "A:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2121, in draw_artist
    assert self._cachedRenderer is not None
AssertionError
```

The top level code is organized as follows:

- a function creates patches from data, and then adds them to an `axis` object -- basically, I get a list of patch objects back, `patches`, where each patch has been added to `ax`; **I think the issue might be here, since the patch objects in `patches` are not *really* connected to `ax`..., they were added to it, but passed by copy, not reference?**
- the animation function uses the number (let's say `n`) received from `FuncAnimation` to reference relevant patch objects, and then calls `ax.draw_artist(patches[n])`

At first I was doing the following:

```
patches = []
...
patch = mpatches.PathPatch(...)
patch.set_animated(True)
ax.add_patch(patch)
patches.append(patch)
...
ax.draw_artist(patches[n])
```

Then, after [reading the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=add_patch#matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch), which suggests that a patch object (possibly now connected to an axes object?) is returned, I tried the following:

```
patches = []
...
patch = mpatches.PathPatch(...)
patch.set_animated(True)
ax_patch = ax.add_patch(patch)
patches.append(ax_patch)
...
ax.draw_artist(patches[n])
```

However, the issue is still the same.

Can you comment on what you think the issue might be, or where I might need to provide additional information in order to figure out the issue?

**EDIT:** the top-level function where the error arises from.

```
def create_animation_from_data(self, vertex_marker_radius=0.25, labels = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], unit_line=0.5, colours=['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange']):

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False, xlim=(-2, 100), ylim=(-2, 100))
    ax.grid()

    print "Initializing patches..."

    patches, patch_indices_per_timestep, num_polys, num_timesteps = self.make_patches_from_environment(ax, vertex_marker_radius, labels, unit_line, colours)

    def animation_function(n):
        relevant_patch_indices = patch_indices_per_timestep[n]

        for polygon_based_index_group in relevant_patch_indices:
            for index in polygon_based_index_group:
                patches[index].draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())

        return patches,

    print "Beginning animation..."       
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animation_function, blit=True)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're understanding everything correctly, but missing a couple of lower-level steps. The `renderer` hasn't been initialized yet, and you're getting an error that reflects that.

In a nutshell, you can't use `draw_artist` before the plot has been drawn the first time.  You'll need to call `fig.canvas.draw()` (in some cases you can get away with just `fig.canvas.get_renderer()`) at least once before you can use `draw_artist`.

---

If you're running into this problem, it's often because you're trying to go "against the grain" and do things that are better not to be handled directly.

What exactly are you trying to do?  There's likely an easier way to handle this (e.g. if you're trying to grab a background, put this part of your code in a callback to the draw event).

---

Let me back up and explain what's happening.  Matplotlib `Artist`s draw on a `FigureCanvas` (e.g. `fig.canvas`) using an instance of `Renderer` (e.g. `fig.canvas.renderer`).  The `renderer` is backend-specific and low-level. You normally won't touch it directly.

`ax.draw_artist` is a lower-level function than `fig.canvas.draw`. More specifically, it's shorthand for `artist.draw(renderer)`.

Initializing the `renderer` is relatively slow, so it's cached and reused unless the figure's size or dpi changes.  This is what the error you're getting is saying: The `canvas` doesn't have a renderer yet.

---

You have a few different options.  You could manually initialize the renderer (the easy way is to call `fig.canvas.get_renderer()`).  However, sometimes you're want to get something (such as the size of a text object) that isn't defined until after it's been drawn.  In those cases, you'll need a "full" `fig.canvas.draw()`.

Usually, though, running into things like this is a sign that there's an easier way to do it.  Often it's best to put code that needs a draw to have happened into a callback to the draw event.  (Especially if it's something that depends on the exact size of the figure -- e.g. a background for blitting).

---

### Update based on code sample

If you're using the `matplotlib.animation` framework, then you don't need to draw the artists inside of the update function.  The animation framework will take care of that step for you.

It sounds like you're trying to display only a subset of the artists you've plotted at each timestep?

If so, you might consider toggling their visibility instead.  As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation


def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    p = Plotter(ax)

    # Note: We need to save a referce to the animation object, otherwise it
    # will be garbage collected and never properly animate.
    anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, p.update,
                                              init_func=p.anim_init)
    plt.show()

class Plotter(object):
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax

    def anim_init(self):
        self.triangles = [self.random_triangle() for _ in range(10)]

        # Initially, show a blank plot...
        for tri in self.triangles:
            tri.set_visible(False)

        return self.triangles

    def update(self, i):
        """Animation step."""
        # Hide all triangles
        for tri in self.triangles:
            tri.set(visible=False)

        # pick 2 at random to show (e.g. your  patch_indices_per_timestep)
        for tri in np.random.choice(self.triangles, size=2):
            tri.set(visible=True)

        return self.triangles

    def random_triangle(self):
        x, y = np.random.random((2,3))
        x += 10 * np.random.random(1)
        y += 10 * np.random.random(1)
        return self.ax.fill(x, y)[0]

main()
```

Comment: Thanks, again! So, what I am trying to do is something similar to what is described in this post: http://devolab.msu.edu/2015/01/20/making-efficient-animations-in-matplotlib-with-blitting/ -- essentially, I am setting up all the patches first, and then in the animation function, I select which patches have "draw_artist()" called on them (as per your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135489/matplotlib-what-is-the-purpose-of-an-artists-animated-state . In the link, they use `set_visible` instead of `draw_artist`. I don't *think* I need to grab backgrounds, but I do need to blit.

Comment: In my post, I added a relevant function that makes the figure, patches, and then the `animation_function` for `FuncAnimation`. Does that help to see what sort of usecase I have?

Comment: Toggling their visibility is exactly what works. Thank very much!